# open specific worksheets in excel through VB

Tags: excel

I have the the following code which creates a csv file for an excel file .It is working fine if i specify the worksheet number (like 1,2 etc) but i want to specify the sheet name.The sheet name may contain some space before or after the name.And this is the problem.I think i should use regular expression but i am not able to figure out how.If the file does contain extra space and if i do not handle it i get a **subscript out of range** error .

```
src_file = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(Wscript.Arguments.Item(0))
dim mine(1)
mine(0)="

Dim oExcel 
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Dim oBook
Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(src_file)
oBook.Worksheets("Failure Report").Activate
oBook.SaveAs mine(0), csv_format
oExcel.Quit
```

Comment: Are you sure the `src_file` workbook really has a worksheet with that name? Also, make sure there are no extra space characters in the name of the worksheet inside the `src_file` workbook.

Comment: @djikay yes i just figured this out .i have updated the question now.

Comment: i am not taking sheet name as input.so i cant use trim.i dont know whether sheet name has spaces or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the worksheet name can only be *approximated* when you try to reference it, then you don't have a lot of choice but to loop over the target workbook's worksheets to find a match. Perhaps something like this (I'm assuming you can adapt this to suit your specific requirements):

```
Sub test()

  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim aWsName As String

  aWsName = "Failure Report"
  For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If InStr(1, ws.Name, aWsName) > 0 Then
      ws.Activate
      ActiveSheet.[A1] = "Matched!"
    End If
  Next

End Sub
```

Although not perfect for all situations, the code is trying to find the worksheet name `aWsName` in the name of one of the active workbook's worksheets. The reason it's not perfect is because it doesn't care what characters come before or after the string `aWsName` that you're looking for. If the names are sufficiently different, then this shouldn't be a problem. You can at least give it a go and see how it works for you.